# Error 500 with htaccess file for https

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, https, lets-encrypt

I have buy a shared hosting on online.net, they have SSL with Let's Encrypt.

I don't understand why i have a 500 error with this .htaccess file, the page is in https, sometime redirected to www.

I want an URL like https://exemple.com without www, always in https.

This configuration file is from [html5boilerplate.com](https://github.com/h5bp/html5boilerplate.com)

```
# BEGIN General rules
<Files .htaccess>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>


# Apache Server Configs | MIT License
# https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-apache


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Error prevention                                                   |
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Disable the pattern matching based on filenames.
#
# This setting prevents Apache from returning a 404 error as the result
# of a rewrite when the directory with the same name does not exist.
#
# https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/content-negotiation.html#multiviews

Options -MultiViews


# ######################################################################
# # INTERNET EXPLORER                                                  #
# ######################################################################

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Document modes                                                     |
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Force Internet Explorer 8/9/10 to render pages in the highest mode
# available in the various cases when it may not.
#
# https://hsivonen.fi/doctype/#ie8
#
# (!) Starting with Internet Explorer 11, document modes are deprecated.
#
# https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bg182625.aspx#docmode
# http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2014/04/02/stay-up-to-date-with-enterprise-mode-for-internet-explorer-11.aspx

<IfModule mod_headers.c>

    Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=edge"

    <FilesMatch "\.(appcache|atom|bbaw|bmp|crx|css|cur|eot|f4[abpv]|flv|geojson|gif|htc|ico|jpe?g|js|json(ld)?|m4[av]|manifest|map|mp4|oex|og[agv]|opus|otf|pdf|png|rdf|rss|safariextz|svgz?|swf|topojson|tt[cf]|txt|vcard|vcf|vtt|webapp|web[mp]|woff2?|xloc|xml|xpi)$">
        Header unset X-UA-Compatible
    </FilesMatch>

</IfModule>


# ######################################################################
# # MEDIA TYPES AND CHARACTER ENCODINGS                                #
# ######################################################################

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Media types                                                        |
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Serve resources with the proper media types (f.k.a. MIME types).
#
# https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml
# https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_mime.html#addtype

<IfModule mod_mime.c>

  # Data interchange
    AddType application/json                            json map
    AddType application/xml                             atom rdf rss xml

  # JavaScript
    AddType application/javascript                      js

  # Media files
    AddType image/svg+xml                               svg svgz
    AddType image/x-icon                                cur ico

  # Web fonts
    AddType application/font-woff                       woff
    AddType application/font-woff2                      woff2
    AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject               eot

    # Browsers usually ignore the font media types and simply sniff
    # the bytes to figure out the font type.
    # https://mimesniff.spec.whatwg.org/#matching-a-font-type-pattern
    #
    # However, Blink and WebKit based browsers will show a warning
    # in the console if the following font types are served with any
    # other media types.

    AddType application/x-font-ttf                      ttc ttf
    AddType font/opentype                               otf

</IfModule>

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Character encodings                                                |
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Serve all resources labeled as 'text/html' or 'text/plain'
# with the media type 'charset' parameter set to 'UTF-8'.
#
# https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#adddefaultcharset

AddDefaultCharset utf-8

# - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

# Serve the following file types with the media type 'charset'
# parameter set to 'UTF-8'.
#
# https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_mime.html#addcharset

<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddCharset utf-8 .atom \
                     .css \
                     .js \
                     .json \
                     .rdf \
                     .rss \
                     .xml
</IfModule>


# ######################################################################
# # REWRITES                                                           #
# ######################################################################

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Rewrite engine                                                     |
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# (1) Turn on the rewrite engine (this is necessary in order for
#     the 'RewriteRule' directives to work).
#     https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteEngine
#
# (2) Enable the 'FollowSymLinks' option if it isn't already.
#     https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#options

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    # (1)
    RewriteEngine On

    # (2)
    Options +FollowSymlinks

</IfModule>

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Suppressing the 'www.' at the beginning of URLs                    |
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Rewrite 'www.example.com' → 'example.com'

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>


# ######################################################################
# # SECURITY                                                           #
# ######################################################################

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Clickjacking                                                       |
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Protect website against clickjacking and other types of attacks by
# informing browsers not to display the web page content in any frame.
#
# https://cure53.de/xfo-clickjacking.pdf.
# https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7034
# http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/03/30/combating-clickjacking-with-x-frame-options.aspx
# https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking

<IfModule mod_headers.c>

    Header set X-Frame-Options "DENY"

    <FilesMatch "\.(appcache|atom|bbaw|bmp|crx|css|cur|eot|f4[abpv]|flv|geojson|gif|htc|ico|jpe?g|js|json(ld)?|m4[av]|manifest|map|mp4|oex|og[agv]|opus|otf|pdf|png|rdf|rss|safariextz|svgz?|swf|topojson|tt[cf]|txt|vcard|vcf|vtt|webapp|web[mp]|woff2?|xloc|xml|xpi)$">
        Header unset X-Frame-Options
    </FilesMatch>

</IfModule>


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# | File access                                                        |
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Block access to directories without a default document.

<IfModule mod_autoindex.c>
    Options -Indexes
</IfModule>


# - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

# Block access to files that can expose sensitive information.
#
# (!) Update the '<FilesMatch>' regular expression from below to
# include any files that might end up on your production server and
# can expose sensitive information about your website. These files may
# include: configuration files, files that contain metadata about the
# project (e.g.: project dependencies), build scripts, etc..

<FilesMatch "(^#.*#|\.(bak|conf|dist|fla|in[ci]|log|psd|sh|sql|sw[op])|~)$">
    <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
        Satisfy All
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# | HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS)                              |
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# Force client-side SSL redirection.
#
# http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/transport-layer-security/
# https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-websec-strict-transport-sec-14#section-6.1
# http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2014/08/18/hsts-strict-transport-security-attacks-mitigations-deployment-https.aspx

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=16070400"
</IfModule>

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Reducing MIME type security risks                                  |
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Prevent some browsers from MIME-sniffing the response.
#
# http://www.slideshare.net/hasegawayosuke/owasp-hasegawa
# http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/07/02/ie8-security-part-v-comprehensive-protection.aspx
# https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg622941.aspx
# https://mimesniff.spec.whatwg.org/

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
</IfModule>

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Reflected Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) attacks                       |
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# (1) Try to re-enable the cross-site scripting (XSS) filter built
#     into most web browsers.
#
#     The filter is usually enabled by default, but in some cases it
#     may be disabled by the user. However, in Internet Explorer for
#     example, it can be re-enabled just by sending the
#     'X-XSS-Protection' header with the value of '1'.
#
# (2) Prevent web browsers from rendering the web page if a potential
#     reflected (a.k.a non-persistent) XSS attack is detected by the
#     filter.
#
#     By default, if the filter is enabled and browsers detect a
#     reflected XSS attack, they will attempt to block the attack
#     by making the smallest possible modifications to the returned
#     web page.
#
#     Unfortunately, in some browsers (e.g.: Internet Explorer),
#     this default behavior may allow the XSS filter to be exploited,
#     thereby, it's better to inform browsers to prevent the rendering
#     of the page altogether, instead of attempting to modify it.
#
#     https://hackademix.net/2009/11/21/ies-xss-filter-creates-xss-vulnerabilities
#
# (!) Do not rely on the XSS filter to prevent XSS attacks! Ensure that
#     you are taking all possible measures to prevent XSS attacks, the
#     most obvious being: validating and sanitizing your website's inputs.
#
# http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/07/02/ie8-security-part-iv-the-xss-filter.aspx
# http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/01/31/controlling-the-internet-explorer-xss-filter-with-the-x-xss-protection-http-header.aspx
# https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29

<IfModule mod_headers.c>

    #                           (1)    (2)
    Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"

    <FilesMatch "\.(appcache|atom|bbaw|bmp|crx|css|cur|eot|f4[abpv]|flv|geojson|gif|htc|ico|jpe?g|js|json(ld)?|m4[av]|manifest|map|mp4|oex|og[agv]|opus|otf|pdf|png|rdf|rss|safariextz|svgz?|swf|topojson|tt[cf]|txt|vcard|vcf|vtt|webapp|web[mp]|woff2?|xloc|xml|xpi)$">
        Header unset X-XSS-Protection
    </FilesMatch>

</IfModule>


# ######################################################################
# # WEB PERFORMANCE                                                    #
# ######################################################################

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Compression                                                        |
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

    # Force compression for mangled 'Accept-Encoding' request headers
    # https://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/pushing-beyond-gzipping-25601.html

    <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
            SetEnvIfNoCase ^(Accept-EncodXng|X-cept-Encoding|X{15}|~{15}|-{15})$ ^((gzip|deflate)\s*,?\s*)+|[X~-]{4,13}$ HAVE_Accept-Encoding
            RequestHeader append Accept-Encoding "gzip,deflate" env=HAVE_Accept-Encoding
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule>

    # - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

    # Map the following filename extensions to the specified
    # encoding type in order to make Apache serve the file types
    # with the appropriate 'Content-Encoding' response header
    # (do note that this will NOT make Apache compress them!).
    #
    # If these files types would be served without an appropriate
    # 'Content-Enable' response header, client applications (e.g.:
    # browsers) wouldn't know that they first need to uncompress
    # the response, and thus, wouldn't be able to understand the
    # content.
    #
    # https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_mime.html#addencoding

    <IfModule mod_mime.c>
        AddEncoding gzip              gz
        AddEncoding gzip              svgz
    </IfModule>

    # - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

    # Make Apache serve the Zopfli compressed version of the requested
    # file if it exists on the server and the browser supports 'gzip'
    # compression

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        ReWriteCond %{HTTP:accept-encoding} gzip
        ReWriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.gz$
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.gz -f
        RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(css|html|ico|js|svg|txt|xml)$ $1.$2.gz [L]
    </IfModule>

    <FilesMatch "\.css\.gz$">
        ForceType text/css
    </FilesMatch>

    <FilesMatch "\.html\.gz$">
        ForceType text/html
    </FilesMatch>

    <FilesMatch "\.ico\.gz$">
        ForceType image/x-icon
    </FilesMatch>

    <FilesMatch "\.js\.gz$">
        ForceType application/javascript
    </FilesMatch>

    <FilesMatch "\.svg\.gz$">
        ForceType image/svg+xml
    </FilesMatch>

    <FilesMatch "\.txt\.gz$">
        ForceType text/plain
    </FilesMatch>

    <FilesMatch "\.xml\.gz$">
        ForceType application/xml
    </FilesMatch>

    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        <FilesMatch "\.(css|html|ico|js|svg|txt|xml)\.gz$">
            Header merge Vary "Accept-Encoding"
        </FilesMatch>
    </IfModule>

    # - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

    # Compress all output labeled with one of the following media types.
    # https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_filter.html#addoutputfilterbytype

    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE "application/javascript" \
                                  "application/json" \
                                  "application/manifest+json" \
                                  "application/vnd.ms-fontobject" \
                                  "application/x-font-ttf" \
                                  "application/xml" \
                                  "font/opentype" \
                                  "image/svg+xml" \
                                  "image/vnd.microsoft.icon" \
                                  "text/css" \
                                  "text/html" \
                                  "text/plain"

</IfModule>

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# | ETags                                                              |
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Remove 'ETags' as resources are sent with far-future expires headers.
#
# https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags
# https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7232#section-2.3

# 'FileETag None' doesn't work in all cases.
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header unset ETag
</IfModule>

FileETag None

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Expires headers                                                    |
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Serve resources with far-future expires headers.
# https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_expires.html

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault                                      "access plus 1 month"

  # CSS
    ExpiresByType text/css                              "access plus 1 year"

  # Data interchange
    ExpiresByType application/json                      "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/xml                       "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/xml                              "access plus 0 seconds"

  # Favicon (cannot be renamed!) and cursor images
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon                          "access plus 1 week"

  # HTML
    ExpiresByType text/html                             "access plus 1 hour"

  # JavaScript
    ExpiresByType application/javascript                "access plus 1 year"

</IfModule>
# END General rules
```

Thank in advance !

Comment: We cannot help with this unless you also post the details of the 500 error from the Apache error log. There is simply too much here in the .htaccess to debug at a glance.

Comment: I havn't access to apache log :/

Comment: Shared hosts usually have some way to access an Apache error log, maybe in the control panel. Otherwise, you will need to contact your host's support to get access to it, or start commenting out sections of this .htaccess until you identify the section that is causing problems.

Comment: Thanks. The issue is Options +FollowSymlinks ... Do you know why ? And if it's dangerous to delete it.

Comment: To reference another answer:

It appears that if the options directive was configured then it's necessary to set up the directory directive too. 
This implies access to the Apache configuration files. 
If this is not the case, we can simply comment the line "Options +FollowSymLinks", considering that this directive is by default "Options All" as states the Apache documentation.'
http://stackoverflow.com/a/14587024

Answer (score 0):

In your apache configuration or virtualhost file, you may need to add AllowOverride All to the directory that has the .htaccess file.

Assuming your .htaccess file is in /var/www/.htaccess

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Comment: It's a shared server, i didn't have access to apache conf file